# Can Play be used without JPA, swapping in your own CRUD implementation?

Tags: rest, jpa, playframework

I am evaluating play for usage as an admin system over a family of applications in an SOA environment.

Each application has their own persistence, and the various CRUD operations can be performed against the REST endpoints in each application.

The free admin is an attraction in play, but I would like to replace the JPA implementation with a REST client that performs CRUD by communicating with each individual application's REST endpoint.

How easy is it to replace the JPA implementation? How would it be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not so complicated.
I work on Siena, a lightweight object mapping framework for NoSQL/SQL and we have 2 modules for play: play-siena which allows to use Siena instead of JPA and crudsiena which provides a Crud based on Siena with some enhancements for date pickers and list/map management.
The play.db.Model design is quite extensible and reusable (it has also been used by Morphia for MongoDB) and the JPA code is quite useful to see what has to be done.
The Crud is not designed to be extensible or inherited so you have to redefine lots of things but, looking at the code, it gives you a good idea of the required mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

CRUD works by checking the Entities related to the CRUD controller. It loads models with similar names (or annotated) and it decides what to show based on the annotations/type of the entities.

If what you want is to have a CRUD screen that shows data provided by a REST service, I think it would be easier for you to just create your own UI. You can probably reuse the layout of CRUD (templates, css, etc) if you want that look and feel, and code the rest easily using the WS library and Play.